# Copy specific values from the header

Tags: php, header

I have following issue. I want to try to avoid using sessions for my php code so I thought about trying to obtain the values I want to have transferred by reading out the header. Is such a thing possible?

```
header('Location: https://whatever.de/v_new_vote_page.php'."?=" . $id_poll);
```

I basically want to obtain $id_poll from the header without the usage of sessions. Is such a thing possible?

Comment: so, basically, you want to send the $_GET based value to v_new_vote_page.php?

Comment: You need to use getallheaders() method to read all request header parameters . If you want to read request URL parameters then use $_GET . Check these links http://php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders.php  http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Comment: Isn't the value already in the `$id_poll` variable?

Answer (score 0):

**try this:**

**sending $_GET based value using header**

```
header('Location: https://whatever.de/v_new_vote_page.php?id_poll='. $id_poll);
```

**On v_new_vote_page.php**

```
<?php

echo $_GET['id_poll'];

?>
```

Comment: in the above example, I assumed there is a value inside $id_poll.